# First-order definition of nonnegative in integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, integers

Given the structure $(\mathbb Z,+,-,\times,0,1)$, what's the easiest way to write "$x\ge0$" in that structure?

I know that this works:
$$\exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d,a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=x$$
because of Lagrange's four-square theorem, but this seems like an unnecessarily complicated way to do it (because the theorem is such a nontrivial result). Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integer $d$ is $\ge 0$ if it is a perfect square or there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xy\ne 0$ and $x^2-dy^2=1$. Here we are appealing to the theory of the Pell equation instead of the Lagrange four squares theorem. Arguably more complicated!

Comment: I'm accepting yours instead because it actually gives another formula.

Comment: There are many formulas, particularly if we admit universal quantifiers. From my point of view the main advantage of the Lagrange version is that it can be efficiently used to reduce the Hilbert 10th problem over the integers to the Hilbert 10th problem over the non-negative integers.

Comment: We _do_ admit universal quantifiers, I believe…

Comment: For first-order definability, universal quantifiers are certainly allowed.  However, the stronger existential definabilty can be important. For example, a major unsolved problem is whether the integers are existentially definable over the rationals.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any more elementary definition of $x\geq 0$.

You can think of this definition as a generalization of the obvious definition of $x\geq 0$ in $(\mathbb{R},+,-,\times,0,1)$: $$\exists y\, y^2 = x.$$

The problem, of course, is that not every positive element in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a square root. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a much more complicated structure than $\mathbb{R}$, and it's not surprising that nontrivial number theory gets involved when you start writing down formulas with quantifiers in $\mathbb{Z}$.